# hping3 Syn Flood attack (DoS) is not strong enough

Tags: security, virtualbox, ddos, server-side-attacks, hping

I'm building an environment to test SynFlood attack. I have 3 VMs to represent SaveClient, Attacker, and the Victim. All are running on VirtualBox. They have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server with the same configuration (1GB RAM, 1 processor).

I tried to establish the attack with hping3 as following:

```
sudo hping3 Victim_IP -p 44 --rand-source -c 1000000 -d 120 -S -w 64 --flood
```

- There is no server running on the Victim client on port 44.

I tried to ping or send a file with nc (netcat) from the SaveClient to the Victim, and i was expecting that the victim is down. However, pinging the Victim or sending files are succeeded with no problem.

My questions:

1. Do I need to run a server (e.g. Tomcat or other HTTP servers) on
   port 44 at the victim to establish a correct testbed?
2. What are other tools required to establish a working SynFlood attack in this
   environment?

All suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for me without any additional parameters

```
sudo hping3 victim_ip -S --flood
```

However, if you lunch the attack from the host or another machine outside the Victim hypervisor(VirtualBox in my case), the attack will be more effective.